# Xcode updation after changing to standalone application

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, updates

Now xcode comes as a standalone application. So if there is  a new version comes, i have to download all the simulators and documentaion again and again. Is there any easy way to do this

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is none. I was having the same issue but chose to just download 1 simulator that I needed and that was not much of a hassle. Unless apple changes back to way xcode was, there are no other way.